# Looping through array of 3 items and return item with unique difference between its elements --Python

Tags: python, arrays

**Question:** There is a array of strings [ABC,BCD,DEG]. The difference between ABC is the same and BCD is the same but in DEG it does not so return that string.

```
import string

arr = ['ABC','BCD','DEG']
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase

for phrase in arr:
    for letter in phrase:
```

Hi all. I came across this question on Geeks for Geeks yesterday. I have been trying to work out the solution but no success. I'm new to Python and I appreciate any help I can get with this.

My thought process is as follows:

- For each element in array, iterate over letters
- Delta between alphabetical index of first/second letter should equal second/third letter for each element for the element to not be returned.
- Return any element that does not pass point 2.

Comment: try using `numerics = [ord(c) for c in phrase]` then you can do `deltas = [numerics[i] - numerics[i-1] for i in range(1,len(numerics)]` from there you should be able to solve i think

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley. I was able to figure it out with your help

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
arr = ['ABC','BCD','DEG']

for phrase in arr:
    chars  = [ord(letter) for letter in phrase]
    deltas = [chars[i+1] - chars[i] for i in range(len(chars)-1)] 
    if len(set(deltas))!=1:
        print(phrase)
```

Out:

```
DEG
```

**Explanation:**

`chars` is a list that containes Unicode point code values for every character in each phrase. So for the phrase `"ABC"` this is `[65, 66, 67]`, while for the phrase `"DEG"` this is `[68, 69, 71]`.

`deltas` is a list of the difference between each adjacent letter pair in a phrase. For `"ABC"` this is `[1, 1]`, while for `"DEG"` this is `[1, 2]`.

`set(deltas)` gives you the unique values in `deltas`, which for `"ABC"` is `{1}`, but for `"DEG"` is `{1, 2}`. By checking if the `len(set(deltas))` is not equal to 1, you only return the phrase which has different deltas.